# What is the best/correct way to make a custom Synology NAS network configuration persistent?

Tags: synology, macvlan

I have a macvlan on my Synology DS218+ that provides Synology access to a few Docker containers running on a Docker-managed macvlan. I create the Synology macvlan using IP commands. What is the best way to make this macvlan configuration persistent across reboots?  The specific IP commands are:

```
ip link add shim link eth0 type macvlan mode bridge
ip addr add 192.168.110.193/32 dev shim
ip link set shim up
ip route add 192.168.110.192/26 dev shim
```

thanks